# Smooth regression algorithms that produce zero training error

Tags: regression, machine-learning, bayesian, nonparametric, gaussian-process

I am looking to fit three regression functions $f_1, f_2, f_3:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. For example, let's say $X_1$ is time, $X_2$ is geographic latitude, $f_1$ is the temperature, $f_2$ is the height of the water, and $f_3$ is the humidity.

I observe a set of $\{(X_{1},X_{2}, Y)\}$ for each of temperature, height of water, and humidity. Note that the $X$s are not the same between temperature, water height, and humidity.

My original goal was to just use linear interpolation to estimate missing points in each of the $f_i$. However, I realized the $f_i$ are correlated, and that each $f_i$ should be used to help interpolate the other $f_j, j\neq i$. So I reformulated my problem as a regression of $F:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}$, where the inputs are time, latitude, dummy for $f_2$, and dummy for $f_3$, and the output is temperature, water height, or humidity.

I am looking for:

1. A regression model (prediction that is continuous and real-valued)
2. Generates zero training error on points we already know. In my application, I would like to have this property.
3. Generates a smooth function as output (as opposed to tree-based algorithms, which tend to perform step-shaped functions)
4. Generates error bars for predictions (frequentist or bayesian). Error bars should reflect zero uncertainty on points we already know.
5. Must be able to handle ~300000 data points. My most promising candidate up to this point was Gaussian process regression. However, this became algorithmically impossible.

Comment: I suspect you want a GAM for spatial data.

Comment: Given the "zero training error" constraint, it seems to me you're going to have to go with interpolation of some form or other, not necessarily linear.

Comment: @jbowman Do you have an idea of which multivariate interpolation method would best allow me use correlations between the f_i to help interpolate? (Along with other criteria if possible)

Comment: @usεr11852 do you have any tips on choosing nonlinear terms fir the GAM to best fit my requirements?